# Mongoose update succeeds but returns undefined

Tags: mongoose, promise

Talk is cheap so I'll show you my code first.

```
const savePostsInOrder = (idx, limit) => {
    if (idx >= limit) {
        console.log("Save completed.");
        return;
    }
    Post.find({
        title: posts[idx].title,
        belongToMajor: posts[idx].belongToMajor,
        belongToMinor: posts[idx].belongToMinor,
    }).then(
        (doc) => {
            doc.map((doc) => {
                if (posts[idx].content !== doc.content) {
                    /* if there is (update) */

                    Post.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: posts[idx]}, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Failed to save: " + posts[idx].title);
                            return console.error(err);
                        }
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Succeeded to update: " + posts[idx].title);
                        savePostsInOrder(++idx, limit);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    );
}
```

`Post` is a mongoose object as you see.

`posts` is a global list of the objects, and I want to update my mongodb documents with the objects of the `posts`.

The problem is, that `Post.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: posts[idx]}, callback)` returns `undefined`, not a promise. `update` succeeds to update the existing db model but it returns `undefined`. Anyone can tell me a solution or a reason?

This is the error message that I got.

> (node:3338) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: thats because it is `asynchronous call` and you are treating it as synchronous thats why you might be getting  undefined, you should use `async/await` and looks like you are not returning anything from your function

Comment: Doesn't `update` have a return value unlike `find`? Then, what kinds of data should I return? Should I make a promise object by myself?

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood about mongoose query, but I think `update` must have `then` function. Take a look at this link.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises

Comment: yes that is correct, but after you are done updating the `doc` you have to return also with some `success param`, which you are not, thats why you are getting error

Comment: and in your `map` both variable names are same `doc` and `doc` which might work, but this is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you. I'll rename outer `doc` to `docs`. And can you give me an example or a link of the document about the `success param` you mentioned?

Comment: its just something you can keep just to know it was success, like `return 'done'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.

If I handle exceptions by using a callback parameter, `update` doesn't return any mongoose objects, so I have to use `catch` except of the callback param.

I don't know the reason why `update` returns `undefined` while `save` does in the same condition.

Anyway, the code amended would be like the below.

```
Post.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: posts[idx]})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Succeeded to update: " + posts[idx].title);
        savePostsInOrder(++idx, limit);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Failed to save: " + posts[idx].title);
        return console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.update` don't return `Promise` it use `callback`

```
Post.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: posts[idx]}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to save: " + posts[idx].title);
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("Succeeded to update: " + posts[idx].title);
    savePostsInOrder(++idx, limit);
});
```